# Substitute Excel Formula Argument (provided by the user) with a Variable

Tags: vba, excel

**Concept:**
Entire Rows are deleted through a macro based off parameters which are represented as an excel formula by the user.  The idea here is that a user can use Boolean formulas that they're already familiar with to evaluate values in a range (read the "Process" below for further clarification).

**Process:**
A user clicks on a button which shows a form.  This form contains two input fields (or parameters); "Column" and "Formula".  The "Column" is the range for which the macro will be cycling through (let's say `$A:$A`).  The "Formula" is an Excel based formula represented as such, in the user parameter field ie `=OR(A1="X",A1="Y")`. However, I've instructed the user to replace any instance of `A1` with `rng`.  I've requested the user to do this because the idea here is that I would replace `rng` with a changing variable in VBA that cycles through all the  cells specified in the "Column" parameter.

**Problem:**
I'm not aware of any way to replace the `rng` representation within the Excel formula with a range variable in VBA.

**Update 4-7-17**
Thank you all for your responses but I'm pretty certain my problem is getting lost in translation.  I'm aware this is my fault, since I didn't provide any code for analysis.  Unfortunately, therein lies the issue.  I don't know what to write.  I'm going to do my best to write some code (that I know is wrong) which will hopefully convey what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Sample Code 4-7-17**

```
Sub SampleCode()
Dim wRng As Range
    Set wRng = Range("A1:A26") 'Let's assume that the values in this range are the
                                ' letters of the alphabet
Dim Counter As Integer


'Cell "B2" will contain a formula that the user has entered
'which is:  =OR(rng="X",rng="M")
'Obviously the formula returns an error in excel (#NAME? to be
'exact) but that's understood.
Dim wFormula As String
    wFormula = Range("B2").Formula

Dim rng As Range 'This variable "rng" is what is represented in the
'formula that was written in Range("B2")

'*** This is where I get stuck.  I know I'm missing code here to
'be able to proceed with my routine below.
'code
'code
'code

Counter = wRng.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To wRng.Rows.Count
    Set rng = Cells(Counter, 1)
    If wFormula = True Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Counter = Counter - 1
Next i

'The ending result should be that row 24 was deleted because it contained
'the letter "X" and row 13 was deleted because it contained the letter "M"
'
'The objective of this code is to use any Excel formula which evaluates out
'to a True or False value.

End Sub
```

Comment: show your code up to now

Comment: re: '*I'm not aware of any way to replace the rng representation within the Excel formula with a range variable in VBA.*' use `.AutoFilter Field:=application.match(myInputvar1, .Rows(1), 0), criteria1:=myInputvar1`

Comment: is it always a row of data that you need the range to apply to, or can it be a grid?

Comment: I've posted sample code for analysis.

Comment: @sous2817 - It's always a row.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jon first you need to declare a Variable of relevant data type, then pass value from Range & finally use where you wish to, like,

Dim Src As Variant
Src= Sheets( "Sheet3" ).Range( "A2:A9" ).Value

Comment: Hi @Rajesh, I'm not sure if this will accomplish what I'm looking for.  See the sample code I've entered above for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey John this code will help you to get the solution,

Public Sub ProcessData() 
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "A"
Dim Lastrow As Long Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row

For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1

If Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value2 Like "*AU*" Or _                 Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value2 Like "*AZ*" Then
.Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't going to work.  If you notice the code I've written above, I'm essentially letting the user write the formula in a cell but replace the absolute cell reference with "rng" to signify that it will evaluate each cell in the column.  This formula that they write can contain any combination of other functions nested within each-other.  As long as the result returns a "True" or "False" it's a valid formula.  I'm essentially trying to convert the excel formula they've written, to a `Worksheet.Function` that can be used to evaluate a range dynamically.